# How can I prevent the repetition of the words I'm looking for regardless of their order?

Tags: c#, regex

I've spent like one hour trying to make a better regex but that's not my cup of tea... I need a regex which will do the following (can provide more if needed):

```
Spd_Engine          #Ok
speedengine         #Ok
enginespd           #Ok
Engine_speed        #Ok
aps_speed_engine    #Ok
engine_speed        #Ok
engine_trq          #Not Ok
speed_rpm           #Not Ok
```

The regex shoud match every line which contains at least (engine && (speed || spd))

So I came up with this:

```
[e,E]ngine[_]?[s,S]p[e]*d|[a-zA-Z]*[_]*[s,S]p[e]*d[_]?[e,E]ngine
```

But I feel it can be improved. How can I simplify it?

Comment: For convenience, could you please edit your question with a description in words of what your validation check is? It's not obvious why aps_speed_engine is acceptable but engine_trq isn't.

Comment: Inside character class you need not use commas, `[eE]` the correct format. But you can use `i` flag to ignore the case checking

Comment: This isn't code review. "Improve" is opinion-based. RegEx is overkill, `input = input.ToLower(); if ((input.Contains("speed") || input.Contains("spd") && input.Contains("engine")) { ... }` will do the same and is more readable.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I didn't manage to find the correct syntax for the `i` flag using [regex hero](http://regexhero.net/)

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry, as this is not the first question about reviewing regex in SO I took my chance

Comment: I'm not a fan of regex an I bet your maintenance programmers wont be either. I'm with codecaster on this

Comment: You can start by asking a more specific question. "I feel" and "simplify" aren't very factual. _"How can I prevent the repetition of the words I'm looking for regardless of their order?"_ is a more precise question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use look aheads to simplify the regex a lot as

```
^(?=.*spe*d)(?=.*engine).*
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string
- `(?=.*spe*d)` positive look ahead. Checks if the string contains `spe*d`
- `(?=.*engine)` another postive look ahead. Checks if the string contains `engine`
- `.*` matches the entire string

[**Regex Example**](https://regex101.com/r/aI0bN4/1)

OR

```
^(?=.*spe*d).*engine.*
```

Droping the second look ahead

[**Regex Example**](https://regex101.com/r/aI0bN4/3)

**Notes on `[e,E]ngine[_]?[s,S]p[e]*d|[a-zA-Z]*[_]*[s,S]p[e]*d[_]?[e,E]ngine`**

- `[e,E]` the commas inside character class does not mean `e` *comma* `E`. You can modify it as

  `[eE]`
- `[_]?` There is no advantage in adding a single character in character class. It is simlar as wirting `_?`
- `i` flag i can be used to ignore cases while matching the regex

Comment: I like http://www.regexr.com/ more

Comment: And also, i was just playing with your expression and after i delete second ?=  nothing changed in the result :/ i cant write it here because two  asterisks are counting as bold here.

Comment: @EmreAcar There are offcourse different ways you can acomplish the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

So if shorter version of this regex is count as simplification then it is what came to my mind

> [e,E]ngine_?[s,S]pe*d|[a-zA-Z]*_*[s,S]pe*d_?[e,E]ngine

VS

> [e,E]ngine[*]?[s,S]p[e]*d|[a-zA-Z]*[*]*[s,S]p[e]*d[_]?[e,E]ngine